# "It’s much more than our names that {makes/make} us..."

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, clefts

Hopefully someone on here will be able to help me resolve a language (grammar) question that came up at work today.

Which of the two sentences below is correct?

1. It’s much more than our names that **makes** us stand out.
2. It’s much more than our names that **make** us stand out.

I think the first one is correct as I believe that 'our names' is effectively treated as a singular concept and therefore makes (the singular verb) is the right choice. This caused some debate in the office though!

A definitive answer on this would be fantastic. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The plural 'names' in the comparison can be a red herring.  It is 'much more [something]' that determines the agreement.  Since 'much' is used (instead of 'many'), the missing noun is non-count and therefore non-plural (like singular).  So you are correct with #1.  cf: "It is water that makes us wet."